# About System Loggers

Tags: java, logging

I want to create a logger which logs all my messages sent to `System.out`.

For this I got to know the java `Logger` class.

But if I understand the purpose of this class, it only allows to write Log messages which are pre defined in the code.

So if I wan't to create a `System.out`. logger I would have to create my own logger class.

```
String dateTime = new String (now("MM-dd-yy_HH!mm!ss"));
                BufferedReader sysLogger = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                BufferedWriter sysWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(currentDir+"/logs/commando/CmdLog_"+dateTime+".txt")));
                String readLine = new String();
                String lastLine = new String();
                readLine = sysLogger.readLine();
                while(iSysLog == 1){ //TODO
                    if(lastLine != readLine){
                    sysWriter.write(readLine);
                    lastLine = readLine;
                    }
                    readLine = sysLogger.readLine();
                }
```

Why is this codenot working?

also: Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what that code is trying to do.

Comment: This isn't even remotely related to eclipse (as your tag would suggest). Also you need to fix the code formatting.

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. `readLine = new String();` is unnecessary. Comparing strings with `!=` will not work.

Comment: And how could I achieve my goal of logging all messages that are passed to System.out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in:

[Java - Capturing System.err.println or Capturing a PrintStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507522/java-capturing-system-err-println-or-capturing-a-printstream)

Still: how can I set the System.out to the console AND the file?

Answer (score 2):

Logger Class use to debug the code or track the code execution easily. We can put logger in debug mode or info mode as we have requirement. It is upto us which info we want to keep in log. You can use log4j or apache common logging.